# CSS li not lining up. Might be a cycle issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-cycle

I've been working on a site, and come into a snag.
I've got various li's inside a single ul.
I'd like for each li to be centred, and not overlap how they are now. Hopefully chaning the li's width will allow me to have a choice of how many I have per row. Currently 4 should fit.
I'm using the [cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/), but I've looked through the FAQ and can't find anything  that describes my issue (I think).
Here is some of the code:

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="./portrait.php">
<h2>Portrait</h2><br />
<div class="slideshow">
<img src="./photos/Abstracted Portrait Study One_Thmb.png">
<img src="./photos/Angelic_Thmb.png">
</div>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="./stilllife.php">
<h2>Still Life</h2><br />
<div class="slideshow">
<img src="./photos/Composition Study One_Thmb.png">
<img src="./photos/Composition Study Two_Thmb.png">
<img src="./photos/Composition Study Three_Thmb.png">
<img src="./photos/Light Bulb Study One_Thmb.png">
</div>
</a>
</li>

[...]

</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#portfoliotextarea li{
width: 200px;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

And the URL: http://www.duffydesigns.co.uk/portfolio/gallery/
Thank you for your time, I hope I'm not just being silly and not seeing straight >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do `float:left` in your li and make a width for the li, also have `overflow:hidden` for ul

Comment: he already has `li` width specified. He just needs to float it left. Remember to clear your floats with an element that has `clear: both;` after the ul.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was misstipe, but when I did the above, with a set HEIGHT (I did already have the width), everything works well! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain what you're referring to, but given that you're using `inline-block` I'm going to assume you're getting some extra whitespace and you're not sure where it's coming from.

If you're using `inline-block` the condensed white-space is preserved between elements, so you'll need to make sure there are no space characters between your beginning and end tags (`</li>` and `<li>`). Newlines count as well.

Additionally, if you want all your elements to center, you need to declare `text-align` center on the `ul` element.

[Here is a fiddle with a demo of what I'm talking about](http://jsfiddle.net/8HGcS/).